# Need to download Packer Openstack Plugin

Tags: plugins, openstack, packer

I need packer openstack plugin to run packer build to create images in Openstack. We have network/firewall issues where the Packer API is throwing "connection timeout error" within the network. So I need the URL to download the Packer openstack plugin so that I can place it under /.packer.d/plugins/ and use it.

I tried downloading the Packer openstack plugin but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Please help with the link to downloaded the Packer openstack plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some misunderstanding here. The OpenStack builder plugin is bundled with the default Packer distribution. It doesn't need to be downloaded. And that has always been the case.

If you provide more details about your problem I might be able help with what's actually wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rickard and yes, you are correct. The Openstack builder plugin id bundled with the default packer distribution only in the older version of Packer till 0.7.5. Whereas in the newer version only packer binary is getting and none of the plugins are bundled in the distribution package. Anyways, this issue has been fixed now. But then I am getting authentication error(error: Build 'openstack' errored: Auth failed. Status code is: %!s(int=404).) now even after providing correct credentials.

Comment: I suggest you send a email to the Packer users list. See  https://www.packer.io/community.html

Comment: And provide as much details as possible, template, env vars, etc. Be sure to scramble any secrets.

Comment: Sure Rickard and the "Auth Failed" issue is resolved now by removing /tokens from the providers API URL. Thanks.. :)